# PHP Idioma Comparação

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso comparar na tabela produtos se o idioma esp e ing estão preenchidos...

Quando eu cadastro o produto ele cadastra como o idioma 1(por).

Depois o cliente tem q cadastrar o 2(ing) e 3(esp).

```
$pdo = db_connect(); 
$listar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ativo = 1 AND id_produto = :cod");
$listar->bindParam(':cod', $cod);
$listar->execute();
$dados = $listar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$produto = $dados->id_produto; 
$idioma = $dados->idioma;
```

Aqui está o codigo para chamar os botoes.

```
<tr>
<td><strong><?php echo $dados->titulo;?></strong></td>                              
<?php if ($dados->idioma == '2'){?>
<td><a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idiomas-cadastrar&cod=<?php echo $dados->id_produto; ?>&img=<?php echo $dados->produto_imagem; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cadastrar</button></a></td>
<?php } else { ?>
<td><a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idioma-editar&cod=<?php echo $dados->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar"></span></a></td>       
<?php { ?>

<?php if ($dados->idioma == '3'){ ?>
<td><a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idiomas-cadastrar&cod=<?php echo $dados->id_produto; ?>&img=<?php echo $dados->produto_imagem; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cadastrar</button></a></td>
<?php } else { ?>                        
<td><a href="painel.php?p=produtos-idioma-editar&cod=<?php echo $dados->id;?>&idioma=3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" title="Editar"></span></a></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem tenho os produtos 603, 544, 292 que estão somente no portugues...
O produto 10 estao nas 3 linguagens (1-por, 2-ing e 3-esp)...

Se o produto estiver cadastrado na linguagem 2 e 3 quero que apareça o botão de editar.
Se o produto não estiver cadastrado na linguagem 2 e 3 aparece o botão de cadastrar.

Comment: Certo... e qual é o problema?

Comment: Se o produto estiver cadastrado na linguagem 2 e 3 aparece o botão de editar. Se o produto não estiver cadastrado na linguagem 2 e 3 aparece o botão de cadastrar.

Comment: O idioma é uma string mesmo?

Comment: isso vem de uma outra tabela

Comment: Não, acho que você não entendeu. A coluna "idioma" é uma string mesmo?

Comment: Sim é uma string....